# Sharing Linq to SQL entities across RIA services

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql, wcf-ria-services

I am creating very thin DTO's and I'm wondering if there is a way of sharing the Linq-to SQL entities themselves.  I've tried.  I created a metadata class inside of a partial class and set the key annotations.  Then I tried to expose the entities in a query from my RIA service.  I get on error though that complains about `System.Data.Linq` in the generated code.  This makes sense, but is there a way to do this without carrying over dependencies on this an other libraries not available in Silverlight?

Note, I'm not using the entity framework because it is way to big for my current project. I'd rather use the thin DTO's than bring in EF for *this* project.

**Edits:**

My question is more generally this: Can LINQ to SQL entities be used directly as RIA Services DTO's and shared by a service?

Comment: I think we'd need a (simplified) example of the contract-interface and it's implementation.

Comment: How on earth does a contract-interface apply?  I'm just wanting to use the same entity classes created by my Linq-to SQL as RIA Services entities without having to create separate DTO's to project them into.  The dependencies I'm talking about are framework dependencies that are not available in Silverlight (i.e. `System.Data.Linq`).

Comment: A quick google turned up this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/958/ which seems to provide a concrete example of using LINQ-To-SQL with RIA.

Comment: I mean the code RIA generates for you which you can expand with "own stuff".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: without taking another approach No.

Long answer:

Not all APIs are supported in the .NET Framework version that is represented by the Silverlight runtime.  For a complete list of supporter APIs see here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2010/03/19/silverlight-4-rc-api-listing-in-one-big-text-file.aspx

If you try to use any DLLs which have a dependency on APIs that are not supported then you will run into the problem you are experiencing.  You cannot push over the LINQ to SQL classes across the RIA wire in their raw state.

The only way this would work is if your LINQ to SQL layer were generated against POCO classes that were mapped to a DataContext such as with this example: http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/LINQ-to-SQL-support-for-POCO.aspx

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.  I'll stick to my DTO's.